# interpolation based on one array values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have two arrays with values:

```
x = np.array([100, 123, 123, 118, 123])
y = np.array([12, 1, 14, 13])
```

I want to evaluate for example the function:

```
def func(a, b):
    return a*0.8 * (b/2)
```

So, I want to fill the `y` missing values.

I am using:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

def func(a, b):
    return a*0.8 * (b/2)


x = np.array([100, 123, 123, 118, 123])
y = np.array([12, 1, 14, 13])

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = func(X, Y)

f = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, Z, kind='cubic')
```

Now, I am not sure how to continue from here.If I try:

```
xnew = np.linspace(0,150,10)
ynew = np.linspace(0,150,10)

Znew = f(xnew, ynew)
```

Znew is filled with nan values.

Also, I want to make the opposite.

If `x` is smaller than `y` and I want to interpolate always based on x values.

So, for example:

`x = np.array([1,3,4])`
`y = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])`

I want to remove values from y now.

How can I proceed with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To interpolate from a 1d array you can use `np.interp` as follow :

```
np.interp(np.linspace(0,1,len(x)), np.linspace(0,1,len(y)),y)
```

you can have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) for full details but in short :

- consider that your array `y` have value with references from 0 to 1 (example `[5,2,6,3,9]` will have indexes `[0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1]`)
- The second and the third argument of the function are the indexes and the vector y
- The first argument is the indexes of the interpolated value of `y`

as an example :

```
>>> y = [0,5]
>>> indexes = [0,1]
>>> new_indexes = [0,0.5,1]
>>> np.interp(new_indexes, indexes, y)
[0,2.5,5]
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the `interpolate.interp2d(` from scipy?Also, I can't understand how `linspace(0,1,len(x) and y` works as input to interp.I mean , we are not supplying x and y but linspace.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.

Comment: @JimHawkins Hello :)
I'm sorry I'll detailed more with an edit

Comment: @George the `interp2d` from scipy is used for 2d array like images. There is no use to apply it on single dimensional arrays

Comment: So, we always use `linspace(0,1,len(x)` in case we have different dimensions?Also, can we use the `interpolate.interp2d` from scipy?

Comment: `interp2d` as I understand is about approximating a function `f(x,y)` which is what I want to do.

Comment: To answer straight to your question about `interpolate.interp2d`, yes you can. The reason you have `nan` is that you try to interpolate values that are not contain between `y.min()` and `y.max()`  for `ynew` and between `x.min()` and `x.max()` for `xnew`

Comment: but if you use : 
`xnew = np.linspace(100,120,10)` and `ynew = np.linspace(1,10,10)` it's working like a charm :)

Comment: @George Let me try and explain. `interp2d` is used if you have two "free" inputs that are mapped to one output. But your situation appears to be different because you seem to want `x` and `y` to change together before you feed them to your function (?) So, technically, your `x` and `y` are both functions of yet another "implicit" variable. Think of it as time `t`. Alexandre's answer is assuming you want to run through `x` and `y` in the same stretch of time. That's where the mysterious `linspace`s come from. They define how you get from the worse times resolution of `y` to the better one of x.

Comment: @PaulPanzer:Ok, thanks for the explanation.I think I understand now.Even though I understand why we are using linspace, I am still trying to figure how it works in this case.And I should always use `linspace(0,1,len` when I have different dimensions?

Comment: @AlexandreKempf:Ok, so how about using scipy 1d?For example, `interpolate.interp1d(np.linspace(0,1,len(x)),np.linspace(0,1,len(y)))` doesn't work for different dimensions

Comment: no of course you can use whatever you want for the new indexes. but the `linspace` trick is very useful :)

Comment: @George Ok let's split it in different problems :

- If you have an array of time let's say [0,1,2,3,4,5] and an array of temperature measure which is twice as big but you know that the first point is at time 0 and the last one at time 5. Then you want to use the `np.interp` to map the two so they have the same shape.
That is the use of `np.interp` and that is where you use `np.linspace`

Comment: - if you have a function that link time with temperature. You still have the [0,1,2,3,4,5] for time and you have f(time*2) for the temperature. 
You can easily calculate the temperature for the time points because you have the correct function for those points. But let's say that for intermediate points you are not sure the function corresponds well. For example for time 2.5 you are not sure the function apply correctly. 
Here you can use the interpolate.interp1d to help you. 
Of course if you know that the function apply for 2.5, just using the function is f(2.5*2) is better

Comment: @AlexandreKempf:Ok, I understood that.And the `linspace(0,1` is just a trick then ( I mean from 0 to 1 ).What about if I want a cubic spline?I can see only scipy has one.And If I try `CubicSpline(np.linspace(0,1,len(x)), np.linspace(0,1,len(y)))` it gives error because dimensions are not the same.How can we deal with this?Thank you!

Comment: - if you have a similar function but take time and humidity as input. You know that the function for particular values of humidity and time is correct but you don't know if it's working for intermediate points. Then the `interpolate.interp2d` is the right function to use. 
Of course once again, if you think the function that link humidity and time to temperature apply correctly on intermediate points you can just use the function.

Comment: @AlexandreKempf:Hmm..Or we can apply first the `interp1d` from numpy , which will give me the new y array and then call the `cubicspline ` from scipy?

Comment: Can you please detail your problem it'll be faster :)
If you're just asking for curiosity, I'll continue to answer to individual questions ;)
First, if you want to use `CubicSpline`, you can do it with the `interpolate.splrep` and `interpolate.splev` in the new scipy version ! 
the example of the documentation is really straightforward. ask me if you have question on the documentation's examples

Comment: Of course you can use `inter1d` then `cubicspline` but for a different purpose. I would recommend to use directly `cubicspline`

Comment: @AlexandreKempf:Ok, thanks for the hepl (upvoted).I may open a new question about using cubic spline

Comment: You should explain your problem with more context so the community can help you doing the right interpolation choice :) have a great day

Comment: @AlexandreKempf:Ok, don't forget to use "@George:" if you want me to receive the comments :)

Comment: @AlexandreKempf:Hi, I opened a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42136280/interpolate-to-specific-time) :)